# EXCEL - My code only runs some times, is there a way to call a private sub by clicking a button on my sheet?

Tags: vba, excel

How do I call this function by pressing a button on my sheet? I want to be able to make sure that my macro runs, and currently it only runs if I open the code and then press enter after the last end sub.

```
Private Declare Function GetKeyState Lib "user32" (ByVal nVirtKey As Long) As Integer

Private Const MOUSEEVENTF_LEFTDOWN = &H2
Private Const MOUSEEVENTF_LEFTUP = &H4




Private Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Range)
Dim Key As Integer

If Target.Count > 1 Then Exit Sub

Key = GetKeyState(MOUSEEVENTF_LEFTDOWN)

If Key And 1 Then
If IsNumeric(Target.Value) Then
    Target.Value = Target.Value + 1
    Application.EnableEvents = False
        Target.Resize(1, 2).Select
    Application.EnableEvents = True
End If
Cancel = True
End If



End Sub
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> How do I call this function by pressing a button on my sheet?

You don't. This method is hard tied to the Worksheet change event.

What you should do is isolate this code into a separate sub, which can then be called in the `Click` method for a button in your sheet.

```
Private Declare Function GetKeyState Lib "user32" (ByVal nVirtKey As Long) As Integer

Private Const MOUSEEVENTF_LEFTDOWN = &H2
Private Const MOUSEEVENTF_LEFTUP = &H4


Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
myWorksheetChange Range("A1") 'or whatever range you want to call it using

end Sub

Private Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Range)
myWorksheetChange Target

End Sub



Public Sub myWorksheetChange(ByVal Target as Range)

    Dim Key As Integer

    If Target.Count > 1 Then Exit Sub

    Key = GetKeyState(MOUSEEVENTF_LEFTDOWN)

    If Key And 1 Then
    If IsNumeric(Target.Value) Then
        Target.Value = Target.Value + 1
        Application.EnableEvents = False
            Target.Resize(1, 2).Select
        Application.EnableEvents = True
    End If
    Cancel = True
    End If

End Sub
```

Comment: This would call upon it using the click method? I guess I'm confused in how the range function works. Does this mean if I click on cell A1 then the sub will run?

Comment: @Dwevon no, when your "Worksheet_SelectionChange" method is called, you are using the range which was cahnged (it is `Target` in your code). So your other method, called from the button in your sheet, needs to know what cell to act on, too.

Comment: I feel like my problem might be misinterpretted. The idea is to turn the macro ON so that it works. Right now, my code works and adjusts the way I want it to, but sometimes it turns off. The idea is to have a "refresh button" or a "kickstart button" that acts like it is just kickstarting the macro. What is happening: I open up my file, and the macro will autoload SOMETIMES. In order to get it to run, I open up the code (View Code) and hit enter after the final End Sub. This "kickstarts" the macro and allows it to work again. Essentially, this is what I need a button to do.

Comment: This might be what you are trying to explain, but I feel like I've portrayed that the button needs to do more than just allow the "active code" to work on its own and act like a "refresh" button.